# Transaction not rolling back with PK violation

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

As per my knowledge if we start transaction (`begin tran`/`commit tran`), it will be completely done or nothing. But when I am executing below TSQL code the first `insert` statement works while the 2nd doesn't.

Background: table A has two columns (ID primary key, Name varchar), and it already had 3 rows of data (ID of 1,2,3).

```
begin tran
    insert into A values (4, 'Tim') -- this works 
    insert into A values (2, 'Tom') -- this doesn't work because it violates the PK constraint
commit tran

select * from A
```

Here is my question: since the 2nd `insert` statement violates the PK constraint and couldn't be committed, I was thinking that everything inside this transaction should all be rolled back because the transaction should be succeed or fail as one unit. But in fact, 'Tim' is added into A while 'Tom' didn't. Does this violate the automicity of transaction?

Comment: You're still calling commit... if you want to rollback you need to call rollback. If you want automatic rollback look at [`SET XACT_ABORT ON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-xact-abort-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Good question, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how transactions work in SQL Server. If you have a "statement-terminating" error, SQL Server just continues to the next statement. If you have a "batch-terminating" error, the transaction is aborted and rolled back.

Now I don't want that behaviour ever.

So the first line I write in every stored procedure is:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
```

That tells SQL Server that "statement-terminating" errors should be automatically promoted to "batch-terminating" errors. Add that statement to the beginning of your script and you'll see that it now works as expected.

Comment: `If you have a "batch-terminating" error, the transaction is aborted and rolled back.` - this depends on many conditions, and SQL Server doesn't behave this way by default. This is an extremely misleading statement.

Comment: That's exactly how it works. And yes it does behave that way by default. Which batch-terminating errors will not cause a transaction rollback? Here's the same viewpoint from another MVP: http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html (See the section on SET XACT_ABORT for an almost word-for-word same description)

Comment: Error 208, at the very least. With `set xact_abort off` by default, accessing a non-existent object terminates the batch, but doesn't rollback the transaction.

Comment: AFAIR, the only guaranteed case when transaction is rolled back after error, without `try/catch` and / or `xact_abort on` is 1205 (deadlock victim). For everything else, "it depends".

Comment: Yes but surely we're not talking about edge cases like syntax errors and invalid object names here. Which ones involving valid code do you see doing this?

Comment: Now we are diverting into pure rhetoric, when one can say that "completely valid code never fails at all". Here are some examples, however: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/126467/list-of-batch-aborting-errors-in-sql-server

Comment: 207, Invalid column name, is generally a compile-time error, but it exhibits the same behaviour as 208 if batch runs in an externally defined transaction. I can't find any comprehensive documentation of which errors behave this way, but I think it would be better to mention these 2 as possible exceptions to the general rule. They are rare, sure, but when they hit, they can be extremely costly.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you handle errors in your transaction. If you catch them, or if you ignore them (it seems you are ignoring them), then the transaction will continue and will commit.

Any decent "transaction manager" of a programming language/framework:

- Will stop the execution of the code and will roll the transaction back, or
- Will *doom* the transaction, so a commit will never be carried out. It will be replaced by a roll back instead.

If you run these commands at the SQL prompt, you are probably not using any transaction manager, and that's why you may be ignoring the error purposedly and carrying on as if everything was good.